# Using two csv files in pandas, how to check if the value of csv1 is in csv2 and, if it's present, get value of csv2's row?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have two .csv files

First one is:

```
ID,NAME
1,A
2,B
3,C
```

The second one is

```
NAME,COMMENTS
A,foo
B,bar
C,foobar
```

If I want to match the NAME column of both files and then get the ID of A, B and C on a third file

```
ID,NAME,COMMENTS
1,A,foo
2,B,bar
3,C,foobar
```

How should I approach it?

Comment: In the shown case `df1.merge(df2)` works, but with some of the default arguments specified its `df1.merge(df2, on='NAME', how='inner')`

Comment: Hey mate, you should throw that as an answer, it really helped me! Thanks